# How to create a sidenav in blueprintjs?

Tags: frontend, sidebar, blueprintjs, sidenav

As the title says. I tried using the Overlay item that comes with blueprint, but that had the issue of only being able to scroll within the overlay. Also tried using reflexbox but that had the issue of not being able to scroll individually within the sidenav vs main content. I'm looking for something like

a | a a a

a | a a a

a | a a a

where the sidebar and the maincontent can scroll independently

Comment: Excellent question! I had the EXACT same problem, wow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this. Simply put the two elements inside a `div` and assign them a `class`. Style it as such:

```
.scroll-div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```